# How do I control the position and size of my images?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, position, wordpress.com

I'm making a website in wordpress.com and I'm trying to figure out how to control where an image is placed? Currently I can only place an image below or above another and it looks really messy. Is there a way to control the coordinates using html or CSS? Preferably html because I want different positions for different images.

Here is the code of my images so far:

```css
    .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 400px;
    }
    
    .image {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    .overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: .5s ease;
      background-color: #008CBA;
    }
    
    .container:hover .overlay {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .projeto01 {
      color: white;
      font-size: 40px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="grid-portefolio">
    
    <div class="container">
    
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main\_Page"><img src="https://insert1australia.files.wordpress.com/2021/04/real-sinister-minister-14-250x250-1-1.png" class="image" alt="Albert Lee Banks Electorate"/><div class="overlay"><div class="projeto01">Albert Lee<br>Banks Electorate</div></div></a>
    
    
    </div>
```

Also note that I'm a beginner at programming. The code above is a mix of templates I found online and some help from a friend.

Comment: I think your question lacks specificity needed for a clear answer. To me, it seems you are asking generally about creating a layout with HTML and CSS. Your question indicates you would prefer an html-only answer, but I don't think that's possible. CSS is the correct tool to build the layout (control the coordinates), while it must go hand-in-hand with the html structure you create. [Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model) is a pretty fundamental concept in this regard.

Comment: Ok, how do you do it with CSS? Maybe that is the way to do it I'm a really big beginner so I didn't know.

Comment: Can you be specific in what you want to do? Otherwise it's a really open question. There are a number of ways to layout/position elements with CSS and the approach to use often depends on the desired result. I would probably suggest [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), but here is a good reference for different layout tools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout

Comment: What's flexbox? Is it a plugin or something?

https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/mybd2j/how_do_i_control_the_position_of_images_using/

^^^ That's a post on reddit I made, it outlines what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `margin` property of css, or I tried it myself, and there might be some other css code overlapping yours since when I changed the width of my three images, they appeared on one line

Edit: @MrMcGoofy, the example code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background: black;" lang="en-US"><head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <style>
        #one{
            /*Add the css you want, but this one wouldn't need margin*/
        }
        #two{
            margin-bottom: /*Play around with the value until you get the desired result , also try to change the margin-bottom to margin-top/left/right*/;
        }
        #three{
            margin-bottom: /*Play around with the value until you get the desired result, also try to change the margin-bottom to margin-top/left/right*/;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/47/sky-690293__340.jpg" alt="1.jpg" width="40%" id="one">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/09/09/16/05/forest-931706__340.jpg" alt="2.jpg" width="40%" id="two">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/12/14/59/milky-way-984050__340.jpg" alt="3.jpg" width="40%" id="three">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using wordpress.com? Because that's where I'm putting my code in

Comment: @MrMcGoofy I haven't used WordPress, but try to change the position using margin since that is the most logical answer to this.

Comment: @MrMcGoofy The other person who answered told you to use position:absolute; and set the top:; and left;, which is an alternative to margin, you can use whatever you want or do you want me to write example code?

Comment: Firstly, I'm really sorry if it seems like I'm missing things that should be basic I'm quite a beginner especially to CSS.

If you could write me an example code or show me an example code using my one that would be great!

Comment: @MrMcGoofy It doesn't matter if you are a beginner or not, since I have only learnt CSS online, I was a noob(and still am), Example Code will be in the answer since it is way too long, also I haven't put the margin value since my images get on the same line once they get the width required.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I assume you mean you edited the answer with the example code?

Answer (score 1):

try to use in your image tag position:absolute; and then use top and left;
for example give top:50px; and left:100px; see what happens, play around with this...good luck
and you can check this to see where i am coming from:
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: I'm still kind of confused. Do you have discord? If you're okay with it could you help me there?

Answer (score 1):

About size it's all about **`width`** and **`height`** properties, and about position.  I think it depends on your website layout, but you can also use **`top`**, **`right`**, **`left`**, **`bottom`**.

Hope I helped you enough.